# Improving SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a written a query in which I create a string and take distinct values from the table based on conditions.

The table has some 5000 rows. This query takes almost 20 second to execute.

I believe that the string comparisons have made the query so slow. But I wonder what are my alternatives.

**Query:**

```
select distinct
   Convert(nvarchar, p1.trafficSerial) +' ('+  p1.sourceTraffic + ' - ' + p1.sinkTraffic + ' )' as traffic
from 
   portList as p1
inner join 
   portList as p2 ON p1.pmId = p2.sinkId
                  AND P1.trafficSerial IS NOT NULL 
                  AND (p1.trafficSerial = p2.trafficSerial) 
                  AND (P1.sourceTraffic = P2.sourceTraffic) 
                  AND (P1.sinkTraffic = P2.sinkTraffic)
where 
   p1.siteCodeID = @SiteId
```

Comment: What is the structure of your table and what indexes are defined?

Comment: In demo example the pmId is the primary key

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: Execution Plan is, select 0% Distinct 43%, nested loops cost 1%, clustered index scan 13%
clustered index seek cost 43%

Comment: The definition of `@SiteId` is not included in the example script,  but make sure that there isn't any implicit data type conversion happening too. Sometimes this can cause significant performance hits.

Comment: This query is taken from stored procedure where @siteid is passed as a parameter

Comment: What he is saying is make sure the datatype of @SiteId is the same as p1.siteCodeID.

Comment: Index sinkId too - and if your table has alot more fields than diplayed here, make compound index on all fields in join condition. String comparisons per se do not make query slow, join on unindexed fields makes.

Comment: BTW, distinct keyword indicates often logic errors in query design. Consider using exists() instead of join and optionally group by to exclude duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a computed column and create an index on that

This article discusses it http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/22/sql-server-computed-columns-index-and-performance/

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.portList ADD
traffic AS Convert(nvarchar,trafficSerial) +' ('+  sourceTraffic + ' - ' + sinkTraffic + ' )' PERSISTED
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_portList_traffic
ON dbo.portList  (traffic)
GO

select distinct traffic from dbo.portList
```

You should also make sure each of the columns in your join relationships have indexes on them:

```
p1.trafficSerial & p2.trafficSerial
P1.sourceTraffic & P2.sourceTraffic
P1.sinkTraffic & P2.sinkTraffic
```

and the column for your filter: `p1.siteCodeID`

Answer (score 0):

this for surely help:

1. if you can remove distinct from your select statement this query will speed up quite a bit. many times, i handle distinct values over the client or web part of the system, like visual basic, php, c#, etc.
   please, remove distinct keyword and time again your query after executing it at least twice.
   however, if you cannot remove distinct then simply leave it there.
2. this is important: convert clustered index scan to clustered index seek or only index seek. that will speed up your query quite a bit. you acquire an index seek from an index scan by modifying the index. typically, a clustered index scan comes from a comparison on a column with a clustered index, which many times is a primary key. i suspect this column is portside.sitecodeid

best regards,

tonci korsano